Cannot execute sql command from file via bash script: ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database '/root/file.sql''
Can anyone tell me, what is the issue here ?
When I execute this COMMAND on my own, everything is fine.

Ubuntu 22.04
mariadb-server 10.11.8

This is the preliminary steps you need to do
mysql
create database testdb;
use testdb;
create table random_table(id int);

Create simple sql file and add this content
echo "INSERT INTO random_table(id) VALUES(10);" > /root/file.sql
Create file /root/file.sh and add this content to file
#!/bin/bash
v_command="mysql --user=root --password=root --host=localhost --database=testdb --execute='source /root/file.sql'"
echo "COMMAND: $v_command"
output=`$v_command`
rc="$?"

This is the output you get:
. /root/file.sh
COMMAND: mysql --user=root --password=root --host=localhost --database=testdb --execute='source /root/file.sql'
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database '/root/file.sql''

I have tried everything.
v_command="mysql --user=root --password=root --host=localhost --database=testdb --execute='source /root/file.sql'"
or
v_command="mysql --user=root --password=root --host=localhost --database=testdb --execute='\. /root/file.sql'"
or
v_command="mysql --user=root --password=root --host=localhost --execute='\. /root/file.sql' --database=testdb"
or
v_command="mysql --user=root --password=root --host=localhost --database=testdb < /root/file.sql"

(this last command gave me a full list of mysql help manual, I do not understand why)

The quotes inside $v_command aren't processed as quoting the argument.

Redirections also aren't processed in the expansion of a variable. You need to use eval "$v_command"

Thanks, eval indeed works, but how can I get return code with eval ?
$? does not work. Always get 0, however, I get an error.

The design is broken. Make the arguments to mysql an array, so that each array element corresponds to one parameter for mysql, and execute it as output=$(mysql "{$array[@]}").
